# storing values in a custom stuct creates compiler error [c++]

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

I am trying to store x and y coordinates in a vector. However the compiler gives me a warning, saying:

> extended initializer lists only available with `-std=c++11` or
>   `-std=gnu++11`

This is my code:

```
struct sPoint2D
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct sSpline
{
    std::vector <sPoint2D> points;
};

int main ()
{

    sSpline path;

    path.points={{10,41},{20,42},{30,43},{40,44},{50,45},{60,44},{70,43},{80,42},{90,41}};
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to create a looped spline between the given points.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50898946/edit) your question.

Comment: Looks like the compiler told you exactly what you need to do then. Since this compiles just fine if you enable C++ 11 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do exactly what the compiler told you to do, enable C++ 11 by passing `-std=c++11` as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it looks like you are trying to compile your code as a C program instead of C++.
Change the configuration of your IDE and try again.

Comment: He is compiling with C++ 98, not C, thus the warning about the old standard. Had he been compiling with C it would go crazy about `vector`'s, classes and a lot of other crazy stuff.

Comment: I am compiling using g++ compiler